# Extracting value from an XML variable

Tags: xml, regex, xsd

The program I'm working with reads in a certain type of file and then runs tests against that file for correctness. The tests are written in XML and I need to add a test which reads a comment line of the input and tries to see if a number is present in that comment. What I'm having trouble figuring out, if i even can, extracting only a certain part of a value that is stored in an XML variable. for example, say the variable is NUMBER = 029. I only need the 29 part and I need to get rid of the 0's.

Now, what I have tried to do is something along the lines of

```
Comment = <random text>29<random test>

 testtype="format" value=".+$NUMBER$.+"
```

The test type if a format test which checks to see if certain text is in a string. What this test does is ignore every character before and after the NUMBER and check that value is in the comment. However this wont work because NUMBER = 029 and the comment only contains 29. This is the only variable I can work with and I've been stuck on this for awhile. I'm that good at regular expressions so if I'm missing something obvious please let me know and thanks to anyone who can help. If there any questions or need more information, please ask.

Edit 1:

What I mean by tests are written in XML is that the tests are in this format

```
<test type="TestType">
  <Test Expression>
<test>
```

I know this question wasn't explained very well, I had trouble myself coming up with what I wanted to say to best describe it.

I am going to look parsing the value myself and hopefully that will work

Comment: I'm not quite sure that I understand your question. However, if you must process an XML file, two options come to my mind: (1) you use XSLT to transform it to some other format you need, or (2) you use an XML parser to process it programmatically. I have the impression that you'd better off with the second option. Probably you can parse your XML file, get the DOM, traverse it to the node(s) you want to extract values from, and finally get the value (or a sub-string of it).

Comment: What do you mean by "tests are written in XML" ?

Comment: Please try to explain your problem more precisely. What are you trying achieve and does XML have anything to do with your problem? BTW, your XML is not really XML at all, so do not try to parse it with an XML parser.

Answer (score 0):

This is my answer to what I believe is your question ("for example, say the variable is NUMBER = 029. I only need the 29 part and I need to get rid of the 0's."):

```
$number = intval($number);
```